# Bing Maps gone on WP7 after Windows 8 install?

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I just recently updated my OS to Windows 8 and also installed Visual Studio 2012 (Windows Phone 8 SDK).

I was playing around with the new interface and trying to see the new features installed and then whether or not my old projects (built in Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone) will load and I noticed a big time problem:

None of the Bing Maps were loading. Hmmmmm, that was weird I thought to myself.
I know that for the Windows Phone 8 Microsoft has transitioned to Nokia mapping so I figured it must have something to do with that in the new SDK.

So I tried opening Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone SDK and loading the older projects (that were  built in that SDK) and the same thing happened... None of the maps will load!!!
I thought maybe it has something to do with the servers/api??? But that looks doubtful.

I'm a high school teacher and we are actually jumping in to developing phone apps using the MS VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone next week and all of the first couple of weeks' lessons are built around mapping (using Bing Maps).

I'll be in a world of hurt if I can't find a solution to loading those maps. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Edit................................
Here are a couple of pictures to show you what the Design looks like and how the emulator is displaying the same data. (Not sure if this is connected but I wasn't able to take a screen capture [PrntScr] when the emulator was running)
[image: Here is the design/XAML]

[image: Here is the emulator. Sorry for the horrendous pic]

Comment: They should work fine. Are they not loading in VS or both in VS and when running the app on the emulator?

Are you using MVVM Light? VS designer crashes if your code touches anything related to the INotifyPropertyChanging interface. And the viewmodel base class in MVVM Light implements this interface.

Comment: @trydis They are actually loading in the VS Xaml markup but not in the emulator of either VS2010 or VS2012 when they are 'run'. Does this mean it has something to do with the emulator?   I am not using MVVM LIght and INotifyPropertyChanging is not implemented in the current project.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but the emulator has a working network connection?

Comment: Yes, there is a working network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are still Bing maps in WP8 SDK, you can find them in this folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries

Comment: In that folder I see Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll. Is that Bing Maps? or the basic Nokia? or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: In that folder is optional library for Bing maps. For Nokia maps you don't need to include any library.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Martin Suchan's correct answer.

In WP8 the Bing Maps control has been deprecated, but is still available to developers who would like to use it for legacy reasons. It's recommended apps developed for WP8 transition over to the new Nokia Maps control built-into the ROM. But the Bing Maps control will still work on WP8 (even though its user experience will feel really out of place for WP8 consumers).

There's no need to add a reference from your WP8 project in order to use the new Map control since it's part of the references used by all WP8 projects.

Comment: Exactly, you can still use Bing maps, if you have large map project you want to upgrade for WP8, and porting it to Nokia maps might be expensive, but for new projects it's recommended to use new Nokia maps.

Comment: So, is the map reference(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.dll) specified by Martin in the directory above, the reference that needs to be included in order for the Bing Maps to work OR is that the built-in map control reference (doesn't need to be connected)? I'm just finding it very strange that even in "VS10 Express for WP" the map control no longer works in the emulator but does in the XAML interface.